# How to model the blood vessel bifurcation?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Kind regards.

I am using blender 3.5.

To model the bifurcation of a blood vessel, I started with a cube and applied the subdivision surface modifier to it.

Then I applied successive extrusions and eliminated some faces to try to obtain the Cross Sections look (Figure A).

However, I am not able to obtain an optimal result of the bifurcation like the one in the attached figure B.

I appreciate guidance on a better method to achieve a better result of blood vessel branching as shown in Figure B.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a Y pipe by :

Going to Edit -> Preferences -> Addons. Search for extra, Add Mesh Extra Objects. Go to the viewport press SHIFT + A and select: Mesh -> Pipe joints -> and add a Y pipe, play with it the edit mode to get your desired shape

Here is a Model I made in Blender 2.93 (Materials included) :

[image]

[BloodVessels.blend](https://www.mediafire.com/file/s7b6t9bmmo910bx/BloodVessel.blend/file)

Comment: Thank you.

To perform the cross section, as shown in the image, should I use the boolean modifier?

Comment: Yes you can use boolean or make it by hand in the editor to avoid shading artifacts

Answer (score 6):

You could use the *Bisect* option of the *Mirror* modifier, and just extrude up your cylinder and move it away from the axis:

[image]

Add some edge loops to sharpen the edges:

[image]

Comment: @TulioJoséNúñezMedina Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, the answer section is reserved exclusively for answering the OP question, to post comments or replies please use the comments section instead. Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).